# Number of ways to arrange n identical stones into piles

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations, recursive-algorithms

Given, there are $n$ stones which are identical. How many ways can the stones be arranged into piles.
Suppose if $n=4$, we can make one pile with $4$ stones or $2$ piles with $3,1$ or $2,2$ or $3$ piles with $1,1,2$ or $4$ piles with $1,1,1,1$. Therefore total $5$ ways.
Is there a recurrence relation for this problem?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)#Generating_function

Comment: If you are thinking about large values of $n$, have a look at the [announcement from 2014 on Fredrik Johansson's blog](http://fredrikj.net/blog/2014/03/new-partition-function-record/) of the record-setting computation of the number of partitions of $10^{20}$.

Answer (score 3):

You’re talking about the number of [partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29) of a positive integer $n$. [This MathWorld link](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartitionFunctionP.html) may also be helpful. There are recurrences, but they’re not particularly nice.

Comment: what is the best way to find out the number of partitions?

Comment: @Alex: [This entry](https://oeis.org/A000041) in the On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences gives Maple and Mathematica code; that might be a reasonable way to go.

Answer (score 2):

You are describing the [partition function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29).  There is a vast literature on it.